# Can git alias use arguments in case i must repeat the same text in two places?

Tags: git

Without using a shell, can I use arguments on git aliases?

for example, my main remote branch is always called "upstream", sometimes git lose the reference with my local branches and say:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master
```

i wanted an alias such as

```
[alias]
    reup = branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/$1 $1
```

so i could just type `git reup master`

(or even better, configure git to always assume remote to be "upstream"?)

Answer (score 3):

Without using a shell? No. But with shell, sure:

```
[alias]
brup = "!f() { git branch --set-upstream-to=${2:-origin}/$1 $1; }; f"
```

Now you can run `git brup dev` to set upstream to `origin/dev` or `git brup dev upstream` to set upstream to `upstream/dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create `git` aliases with parameters, you just need the simple trick of putting # at the end of the line otherwise git will append again the parameters.
So in your case this should work:

```
[alias]
    reup = "!git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/$1 $1 #"
```

But this is not your true question in fact, which is more like: how to rename origin to upstream.

Have a look at `git-remote`, that should help:

```
   rename
       Rename the remote named <old> to <new>. All remote-tracking branches and configuration settings for the remote are updated.
```

So try:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
```

If that works how you need it then you do not need the alias at all.

(Otherwise the "origin" name is hardcoded here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/69d71ec4433d21f464d83b529432856da2387bba/remote.c#L675 so you would need to change it and recompile git)

Comment: i do have both upstream and origin. origin is my user forks. upstream the team repos. i do sync much more to/from upstream, but i do not want to push to upstream by default (which would happen if renamed it... but good suggestion though)

Comment: You should add these constraints in your question. If you need both `origin` and `upstream` then I see no way to set a default except doing some kind of alias like you did.

Comment: The question starts with "Without using a shell…" while the answer is an alias with `!` — i.e., a shell! ;-)